# While traversing graph in BFS order gives Segmentation fault (core dumped) in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I am **checking if the path is present or not in the undirected graph between two vertices**. Here I make a undirected graph by using adjacency list. I am traversing from source vertex to destination vertex in BFS order to check if a path is present or not and also maintaining which vertices are visited.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

// This class represents a undirected graph using adjacency list 
// representation
class Graph
{
    int V;    // No. of vertices
    list<int> *adj;    // Pointer to an array containing adjacency lists
public:
    Graph(int V);  // Constructor
    void addEdge(int v, int w); // function to add an edge to graph
    bool isReachable(int s, int d);  
};

Graph::Graph(int V)
{
    this->V = V;
    adj = new list<int>[V];
}

void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w)
{
    adj[v].push_back(w); // Add w to v’s list.
}

// A BFS based function to check whether d is reachable from s.
bool Graph::isReachable(int s, int d)
{
    // Base case
    if (s == d)
      return true;

    // Mark all the vertices as not visited
    bool *visited = new bool[V];
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        visited[i] = false;

    // Create a queue for BFS
    list<int> queue;

    // Mark the current node as visited and enqueue it
    visited[s] = true;
    queue.push_back(s);

    // it will be used to get all adjacent vertices of a vertex
    list<int>::iterator i;

    while (!queue.empty())
    {
        // Dequeue a vertex from queue and print it
        s = queue.front();
        queue.pop_front();

        // Get all adjacent vertices of the dequeued vertex s
        // If a adjacent has not been visited, then mark it visited
        // and enqueue it
        for (i = adj[s].begin(); i != adj[s].end(); ++i)
        {
            // If this adjacent node is the destination node, then 
            // return true
            if (*i == d)
                return true;

            // Else, continue to do BFS
            if (!visited[*i])
            {
                visited[*i] = true;
                queue.push_back(*i);
            }
        }
    }

    // If BFS is complete without visiting d
    return false;
}

// Driver program to test methods of graph class
int main()
{
    // Create a graph given in the above diagram
    int x,y,a,b;
    cin>>x>>y;
    Graph g(x);
    while(y--){
        cin>>a>>b;
        g.addEdge(a, b);
        g.addEdge(b, a);
    }
    int u, v;
    cin>>u>>v;
    if(g.isReachable(u, v))
        cout<<1<<endl;
    else
        cout<<0<<endl;

}
```

It gives me `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error for following input:-

```
4 4
1 2
3 2
4 3
1 4
1 4
```

My input format:-
the number of vertexes than the number of edges in one line.
Edge Vertices in the next number of edges lines.
In last lines two vertex between which path is present or not.

Expected Output is `1` for above input.

I am thinking that error is occurring after `for (i = adj[s].begin(); i != adj[s].end(); ++i)` but I am unable to correct it.
Can anyone please help me to correct this issue?

Comment: Crashes are best solved with the help of a *debugger*. I recommend you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger to catch the crash and locate where in *your* code it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My input format:- the number of vertexes than the number of edges in
>
> one line. Edge Vertices in the next number of edges lines. In last
>
> lines two vertex between which path is present or not.

#### Possible cause

Are your input nodes ranges from `0` to `V - 1`? If your input nodes range `[1... V]`, then it will cause array out of bound exception. For quick check, try initializing `adj` and `visited` array's size `V + 100` and check how it does.

Comment: In addition to this, some input validation to make sure that the input is within range would be good to have.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
4 4
1 2
3 2
4 3
. .
```

You say number of vertices as `4` and then `adj = new list<int>[V];`
So `adj[0]` to `adj[v-1]` are valid.
Then you try to create an edge from `4` to `3` and try to access `adj[4]` in `addEdge()` which is out of bounds.

Either allocate `V+1` `lists` or while adding edge subtract 1 from the vertex number.